# How to retrieve a single field from a table in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

```
$price = DB::table('price')
       ->where([ 
        ['days_id', $days AND 'deals_id', $selected_deal] ])
       ->pluck('price');
```

I'm using this code to get single price only but it give me all prices where these to conditions are coming.

**Record in database:**
[image]

Comment: As I understand from your question you should just sum those up, right?

Comment: No sir, I want only one price not many

Comment: Your code will return the `price` for every instance found in the `price` table after parsing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck)

> The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key

I don't know what do you exactly want to achieve but you should to take a look on `first`, `last` or `filter` method. If think the last one will be the best for you.

Comment: Both filters are Important. I want only one field where these both mathes

Comment: $price = DB::table('price')
       ->where([ 
        ['days_id', '2' AND 'deals_id', '4'] ])
       ->pluck('price');

This is giving me these results 

Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => 40 [1] => 60 [2] => 80 [3] => 100 [4] => 120 [5] => 140 ) )

Answer (score 1):

Using value() method you can get single value/field from the table you want

```
$price = DB::table('price')
       ->where([ 
        ['days_id', $days AND 'deals_id', $selected_deal] ])
       ->value('price');
```